# How to use new compiled statements in sqldelight with sqlbrite?

Tags: android, sqlbrite, sqldelight

Since I cannot obtain SQLiteOpenHelper instance from BriteDatabase, how can I create compiled insert/update/delete statement from my model? Methods that return SqlDelightStatement are marked as deprecated in SqlDelight 0.5.1.
I'm using SqlBrite 0.8.0 and I see there's a `BriteDatabase#executeInsert(String, SQLiteStatement)` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT December 27th 2016:**
SQLBrite version 1.1.0 and up now exposes its own `getWritableDatabase()`

It's worth noting that calling `getWritableDatabase()` can potentially create or migrate a database so make sure you're calling it from a background thread!

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to call `close()` on database object?

Comment: only once you're done using the database for good. If you close a database while SQLBrite is still being used you'll run into errors. So when your application is going to close you can call close

Comment: Would notifications still trigger if the write doesn't happen via the BriteDatabase?

Comment: no, everything has to go through BriteDatabase if you want the reactive parts to work

Comment: @Anstrong is there any way to use `executeInsert` with conflict algorithm?

Comment: yes, use the SQLite syntax for it: https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

looks like

    `INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE table (column) VALUES ('sample')`

Comment: It seems that SqlBrite has migrated to `SupportSQLiteDatabase` - making this solution non-feasible.  If SqlDelight doesn't also migrate, it seems compatibility between these two libraries is already being deprecated.